# Display data if Count(distinct) is 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server 2008

SQL Query displays IP address if present

```
SELECT [IP_ADDR1_TEXT], COUNT(distinct [IP_ADDR1_TEXT]) as Instances
FROM sem_computer, [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER]
WHERE sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID = [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER].COMPUTER_ID
AND [IP_ADDR1_TEXT] = '10.10.10.10'
GROUP BY [IP_ADDR1_TEXT]
```

Output

```
IP_ADDR1_TEXT   Instances
10.10.10.10         1
```

If IP address count is 0, the output is null.

How do I modify the query so that Instances outputs 0, next to the non-existant IP address, i.e.

```
SELECT [IP_ADDR1_TEXT], COUNT(distinct [IP_ADDR1_TEXT]) as Instances
FROM sem_computer, [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER]
WHERE sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID = [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER].COMPUTER_ID
AND [IP_ADDR1_TEXT] = '10.10.10.11'
GROUP BY [IP_ADDR1_TEXT]
```

Should output

```
IP_ADDR1_TEXT   Instances
10.10.10.11         0
```

EDIT

Screenshot of VIEW

[image]

IP_ADDR1_TEXT is an ALIAS to

Column
CAST(CASE WHEN IP_ADDR1 < 0 THEN 0xFFFFFFFF + IP_ADDR1 ELSE IP_ADDR1 END / 256 / 256 / 256 & 0xFF AS VARCHAR) + '.' + CAST(CASE WHEN IP_ADDR1 < 0 THEN 0xFFFFFFFF + IP_ADDR1 ELSE IP_ADDR1 END / 256 / 256 & 0xFF AS VARCHAR) + '.' + CAST(CASE WHEN IP_ADDR1 < 0 THEN 0xFFFFFFFF + IP_ADDR1 ELSE IP_ADDR1 END / 256 & 0xFF AS VARCHAR) + '.' + CAST(CASE WHEN IP_ADDR1 < 0 THEN 0xFFFFFFFF + IP_ADDR1 ELSE IP_ADDR1 END & 0xFF AS VARCHAR)

Comment: The reason it doesn't display is because you are using the antiquated join syntax which turns this into an inner join. You should use the newer ANSI_92 syntax for joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT [IP_ADDR1_TEXT], COALESCE(COUNT(distinct [IP_ADDR1_TEXT]),0) as Instances
FROM sem_computer LEFT JOIN [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER]
  ON sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID = [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER].COMPUTER_ID
AND [IP_ADDR1_TEXT] = '10.10.10.11'
GROUP BY [IP_ADDR1_TEXT]
```

Comment: it still doesn't display if count is 0. I'm using MS SQL Server 2008

Comment: Witch table belong [IP_ADDR1_TEXT] column ? And why join the two table if you select and filter only one fields ? Can you post the table structure ?

Comment: see updated answer, however what relation between sem_computer and v_sem_computer ? 1 - 1 , 1 - n , n - 1 , n - n ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
SELECT [IP_ADDR1_TEXT], COUNT(distinct [IP_ADDR1_TEXT]) as Instances
FROM sem_computer
Left JOin [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER] On sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID = [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER].COMPUTER_ID
WHERE [IP_ADDR1_TEXT] = '10.10.10.10'
GROUP BY [IP_ADDR1_TEXT]
```

Comment: it doesn't display if count is 0

Comment: @Glowie Seems like you got your answer. I forgot to add the IsNull() check on the Instances column.